# Infrastructure automation with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am currently employed as part of the IT infrastructure team of a large company. We manage over 350 location including 6 warehouses. We basically take care of everything from networking and servers to ups and ovens. Nothing is in the cloud.

Many times I had tasks which were repetitive and I would like to automate this tasks.

I heard about Ansible and I am willing to take a course of it but I wanted to ask the community first if learning Ansible for this type of job would really be helpful.

What type of devices/OS can be controlled via Ansible? I want for example to first start automate the configuration of UPS devices ( which allow access via http and ssh. I am not sure what type of OS does the UPSs have). Would Ansible help?

As for my skills I have experience in programming with C# and C/C++. I also worked with .NET Core, Angular and Xamarin

Comment: If you have a specific question about Ansible, I'm sure you can find ready assistance here, but it seems you are looking for very general information you can find in Ansible's own documentation or countless tutorials.  The short answer is "if you can `ssh` to it, Ansible can manipulate it"- beyond that, please try to have a specific question or problem to which you seek a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I've used Ansible to configure servers, network devices like routers and etherswitches, and even rack power strips.  I think Ansible could be a good tool for you.

A lot depends on how the device can be configured via ssh/telnet/http, but because Ansible doesn't need agent software running on the device, it can be a good tool to try.  And automating control over more devices in your architecture is a win.